# How to change the filter method of a higher order component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, higher-order-components

How would I go about changing the filter method of a component when wrapping it with a HOC? For example assume:

```
const LoaderHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class LoaderHOC extends Component{
    render(){
      <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }
}
export default LoaderHOC;
```

and now with a stateless component which would resemble something like this:

```
const Results = props =>
 <div>
    {props.results.filter(item<20).map((item,index)=>
       <div>
           <SomeOtherComponent/>
       </div>
     )}
 </div>;
 export default Results;
```

Now would I go about changing the `filter(item<20)` from the Results component by wrapping it with the HOC to something like `filter(item=20)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by passing a comparator function

```
const defaultComparator = (item) => {
    return item > 20;
}
const FilterHOC = (Component, comparator=defaultComparator) => {
   return (props) => {
        <div>
            {props.results.filter(comparator).map((item,index)=>
               <div>
                 <Component/>
               </div>
            )}
        </div>;
   }
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
const Comp = FilterHOC(SomeOtherComponent, (item) => {
    return item === 20
})
```